# Check the type of element for "this"

Tags: javascript, html

When using this code:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="n();">
```

Now how can I get the element type and if it's an `img` get the `src` value but if it's an `a` get the `href` value.

I've tried:

```
function n(){
    document.print(this);
    if(this === "a"){
        window.open(this.href);
    } else if(this === "img"){
        window.open(this.src);
    }
}
```

[**Not jQuery**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8PMW7/show/)

Comment: I liked **NOT jQuery** alert :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined by how the function is called.

The click event handler is being called in the context of the element, so there `this` is the element.

`n` is being called with no explicit context though, so it uses the default context: `window`.

If you want to call `n` in the context of the element, then you need to do so explicitly:

```
 onclick="n.call(this);"
```

Once you have that, you can test `this.tagName` to see what type of element it is.

---

Alternatively, pass `this` as an argument to `n`:

```
n(this);
function n(element) {}
```

---

Alternatively, stop using intrinsic event attributes. They force you to make your functions global and litter your HTML with JavaScript. Bind your event handlers programatically.

```
document.getElementById('myAnchor').addEventListener('click', n);
```

Comment: That's because you've ignored half my answer.

Comment: This `n.call(this)` trick is great. But I thought instead of checking `.tagName` one could do `var srcHref = this.href || this.src;`.

Comment: First: `Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined` — I said that using intrinsic event handler attributes forced you to make your functions globals. You've configured JSFiddle so your function isn't a global, but is defined within a function that is called `onload`.

Comment: Second: I said "Once you have that, you can test `this.tagName` to see what type of element it is." - you are testing `this` not `this.tagName`.

Comment: Third: `this.tagName` returns `"A"` or `"IMG"` not `"a"` or `"img"`.

Comment: @Quentin Maybe `this.tagName.toUpperCase()` for more stability?

Answer (score 1):

For check type of clicked element you can use below code. Here I have used the tagName attribute for this work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
    function n(elem){
       if(elem.tagName == "A"){
            window.open(elem.href);
        } else if(elem.tagName == "IMG"){
             window.open(elem.src);
        }
    }
</script>

<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="n(this);"> suman</a>
<img onclick="n(this);" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/220px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt="sss"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't test it, but if Quentin's answer is true (and his solid 284k (!) reputation supports this) this won't work.

Comment: @SumanBogati I'm sorry. I indeed misinterpreted the code. I read too quickly.

Comment: I tested it, and this approach doesn't work. tagName is not preserved when passing this.

Comment: @Numbers how are you testing, If I make the html file with above code and run it into browser, its working fine at my side, can you please tell about it.

Comment: I apologize, it was me. The way I tested it does not work, but it depends on window.open and not on the logic, which is indeed correct. I deleted my answer which reported a false statement.